# Rerun an angular controller on next load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

How can I specify that I want the next load of this controller to actually run the controller body? Normally if the page has been visited, only the `resolve` are re-run but not the controller bodies.

I have a case where a user updates their profile photo. So I want to have the next load of their profile controller to actually run the body and do the `$scope.photo = myPerson.getPhoto()` again.

My setup is pretty standard like:

```
  .state('profile', {
    url: '/profile',
    templateUrl: 'templates/profile.html',
    controller: 'ProfileCtrl',
    resolve: {
      myPerson: function() {
        return Person.getMine();
      },
    }
  })
```

Comment: try `reload:true`...works in `$state.go()` not sure about in provider config though

Comment: @charlietfl I don't want a single transition to be uncached since there are many possible ways in my app to get back to your own profile page. I just want that page out of the cache.

Comment: not sure what the implication is...i'm suggesting putting that right in the state config shown since that's the one you want reload on

Comment: @PaulTarjan, why doesn't it. Normally it would, if you go back to that state from another non-descendant state. [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BEp4c4MZuwP4LctLn4XU?p=preview)

Comment: @NewDev I tried to get your plunk to be as close as I can to my app, and you're right, it keeps re-running the controllers... Any ideas what else could be caching my controllers? http://plnkr.co/edit/3X5R6T0NM5rfWLwLLupx?p=preview

Comment: Are you using something like ionic? It caches views, AFAIK.

Comment: @NewDev yes, I am using ionic. Do you know how to purge that cache for a specific view? I guess I'll have to re-ask my question in that light.

Comment: @PaulTarjan, I'd suggest a new question, yeah. I haven't worked enough with ionic to help